# SweetAlert 2 v9 - how to write and insert a custom css?

Tags: css, sweetalert2

Where to declare a CSS class and how to pass it to customClass object?

I am trying to change the default layout of the SweetAlert 2 container, and I suppose I have to use the customClass object. However, it only receive strings.

I read the documentation, but it's not as thorough in regards to customClass, any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#customClass

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi as I said, I have read the documentation but it doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate which container you want to add this custom class and the name of the new class, see the example below:

```
customClass: {
  container: 'container--modifier',
  popup: '...',
  header: '...',
  title: '...',
  closeButton: '...',
  icon: '...',
  image: '...',
  content: '...',
  htmlContainer: '...',
  input: '...',
  inputLabel: '...',
  validationMessage: '...',
  actions: '...',
  confirmButton: '...',
  denyButton: '...',
  cancelButton: '...',
  loader: '...',
  footer: '....'
}
```

Here is the documentation:
https://sweetalert2.github.io/#customClass

After add this custom class, go to your css file and set the properties you want for the element.

Comment: But where do I declare CSS rules for e.g. container customClass?

Comment: In your css files.